# Queue Worker Failing w/ Illuminate/Foundation Error

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I am using supervisor to run a queue work and it is failing with the following error:

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `'&'' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' in /Users/chris/Development/project/repo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 475
```

This error shows up repeatedly in the worker logs.

Has anyone ever encountered this? Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: We need more information. My guess is that you actually have an error in your code. Can you post those lines of code from the Laravel code? (it may be different between versions). Also, can you try to run the same command you configured on the supervisor, but running it on the command line? that may give you a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the Supervisor works were using a different version of PHP than my CLI and web server. I updated the php path to the correct bin in the worker config and all is well.

Comment: Exactly. Been trying to set up laravel 5.3 project on a server that has php5.5 installed, but I keep getting the error. At the end turns out laravel 5.3 needs php5.6+